# Make app under NAT work like it's not under it

Tags: proxy, nat, vps, reverse-proxy

I have the "server" at my home under NAT(ipv4) with program that open 1234 port, but it request static ip to work correctly. I want to use such ip from my VPS.

VPS come with ipv4 and ipv6. I want to connect to vps:ipv4 and forward/revers proxy/redirect all raw traffic from ipv4:1234 port of mine  home server under NAT to VPS ipv6:1234 port.

How can I archive this?

Thanks.

Comment: @roaima NAT on my home where the "server" with program located. And I have pretty standart vps with ipv4 and ipv6 that I want to use as external ip for my program...

Comment: Your question update is a lot clearer now. Thank you

Comment: There are quite a few approaches to this. Using iptables to forward the traffic, a dyndns + proxy (like haproxy), or perhaps an app/service like pagekite. Can you elaborate on why is a static IP required? It would make it easier to suggest you the best option. Perhaps just the dyndns is actually already enough.

Comment: @Zip Unfortunately, not enough. Program is the service that communicate with other the same programs and it requests to be on the list of peers with the same IP.

Comment: Please add that to your question where it can be easily read. Please also explain whether your program uses UDP or TCP or its service. Some background would help